# Github Pull Request changes

Tags: github

I forked the master repo and made a branch called dev
I made a lot of commits to the dev branch to add functionality 
I then did a pull request to merge dev with master

But I have gotten comments on my dev branch for changes after the pull request

Do I make new commits to the dev branch and then submit a new pull request? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Github merges the branch so all changes you make on that branch are automatically included in the pull request. So leave that pull request and push the extra changes to github and then check the exiting pull request - you should see the new changes